# Selenium webdriver unable locate href element in menu

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, xpath, href

I am using Selenium Webdriver and Java. I keep getting an InvalidSelector exception error: I am trying to click on a link that is in an href tag with javascript. The link is in a submenu that you hover over and then the links appear. Here is my code that doesn't work. I would like to click by the name:

```
String xpath = String.format(".//div[@class='submenu_c1'][11]");
WebElement subelement = getDriver().findElement(By.xpath>(xpath));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", subelement);
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="submenu" style="position: fixed; display: block; top: 149px; left: 444.5px;">
<div id="shadow" class="divEffectSubList" style="height:520px;width:900px;padding:5px;">
<div class="submenu_c1" style="width:900px;">Search</div>
<ul id="sublist">
<li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
<a href="javascript:hrefSubmit(startPageForm, 'searchDataEvents');">Data Event</a>
</li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
</ul>
<ul id="sublist">
```

Comment: Do you have a component which will perform the hover action ? Only after that you elements dom will visible And why do u use java script executor to click your element ?

Comment: Yes it is:        getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"search\"]")).click();
  WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"search\"]"));
  Actions action = new Actions(driver);
 
        action.moveToElement(element).build().perform();

Answer (score 0):

It seems your `div` closes and contains only the "Search" text. Also the `a` element is not the 11th element.

One more thing, dosn't have to do with the question, it seems you have 2 `ul` elements with same id, giving same id to multiple DOM elements is not a wise thing

Hope I helped

Comment: I am the tester not the developer.  so the 2 ul element id issue is something I cannot change.  I agree with you I saw that and thought this is very wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As Slava has pointed out the markup is not really good.

The xpath expression you are looking for is 
    `".//ul[@id='sublist'][1]/li[13]/a"`

I would recommend to use css selectors instead and improve the html markup for testability. Take a look on this [guide from sauce labs folks](https://saucelabs.com/resources/selenium/css-selectors)

Also the console on firefox or on chrome is your friend, to eval an xpath expression type

`$x(".//ul[@id='sublist'][1]/li[13]/a")`

press enter and you get the results on the console.

For css selectors you can use
`document.querySelectorAll("ul#sublist:nth-of-type(1) li:nth-of-type(13) a")`

Also there is no need of the JavaScriptExecutor, you can find the WebElement directly and invoke the click on the webelement.

And finally you are formatting the locator without anything so no need to use String.format.

Comment: I am now getting NoSuchElementException the code is now:   WebElement subelement = getDriver().findElement(By.xpath(".//ul[@id='sublist'][1]/li[11]/a"));